# Applying Gauss Divergence law

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A $y$ by $z$ flat plate centered at $(0,0,0)$ is located $x_0$ away from a point charge at $(x_0,0,0)$ having a charge of $Q$. What is the electric flux through the plate due to point charge?

Can somebody show me how to solve it using $Flux= ∮\vec{E}^\ \cdot \vec{n}^\ dS$ using spherical coordinates and Cartesian coordinates and possibly point out the mistakes in mine?

Cartesian
$$ \oint_s \vec{E}^\ \cdot \vec{n}^\ dS= \iint \frac{\lambda}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{\mathbf{r-r'}}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|^3}\cdot \vec{n}^\ dS = \iint \frac{\lambda}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{x-x_{0}}{((x-x_0)^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}} dS = \iint \frac{\lambda}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{x-x_{0}}{((x-x_0)^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}} dydz$$

Spherical
$$ dydz = \frac{\partial(y,z)}{\partial (\phi,\theta)}d\phi d\theta = -\sin^2\phi \cos \theta ~d\phi d\theta$$
$$ \oint_s \vec{E}^\ \cdot \vec{n}^\ dS=  \iint \frac{\lambda}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{ dS}{|\mathbf{r}|^2}i\cdot \vec{n}^\ =  \iint \frac{\lambda}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{ dS}{|\mathbf{r}|^2}(\cos \theta \sin \phi ) = -\iint \frac{\lambda}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{ d\phi d\theta}{|\mathbf{r}|^2}(\cos^2 \theta \sin^3 \phi ) =  \iint \frac{\lambda}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{ dS}{|\mathbf{r}|^2}(\cos \theta \sin \phi ) = -\iint \frac{\lambda}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{ d\phi d\theta}{x_0^2}(\cos^4 \theta \sin^5 \phi ) $$

Comment: Why do you think that you have mistakes in your calculations?

Comment: Because x_0=5 cm, y=10 cm and z =10 and q = 1×10^-8 C. The answer should come up 188.3 but its not.coming.

Comment: I saw this question with a field-theory tag but it should be calculus or related, honestly.